# DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I'm adding data using `footer template` and I have button to add. So when I try to add

error '`System.Data.DataRowView`' does not contain a property with the name '

It shows error in this line:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "30px"  HeaderText ="Name">
    <FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblMembershipName" runat="server" width ="150px"
             Text='<%# Eval"MembershipName")%>'> </asp:Label**>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change: `Text='<%# Eval"MembershipName")%>'` to `Text='<%# Eval("MembershipName")%>'`

You where missing the opening ( of the Eval function.

Comment: I have corrected the syntax it but still the problem persists.This error DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'MembershipName'.

Answer (score 1):

The problem looks to be in your binding statement assuming your code is as you posted and not a copy typo:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMembershipName" runat="server" width ="150px"
    Text='<%# Eval"MembershipName")%>'> </asp:Label**>
```

Your missing a bracket as it should be:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMembershipName" runat="server" Width="150px"
    Text='<%# Eval("MembershipName") %>' />
```

Also verify that what you are binding to has a field called `MembershipName`.

Answer (score 1):

You've ommited a `(`, it should be:

`Eval("MembershipName")` instead of `Eval"MembershipName")`.

And instead of  `</asp:Label**>` you should write  `</asp:Label>`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to databind data in the footer - ensure you have nothing that looks like this in the footer section - posting the code would help loads.

text = '<%#....

Ross